# Как уменьшить количество if до 3? Не использовать switch case

Tags: java

Задача показать минимальное и максимальное значение основываясь на том какое слово запишут в args[].Если ничего не передали вывести значения всех примитивных типов.Если написали что-то некорректное вывести "Error"

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i=0;i<args.length;i++) {
        
        if(args[i].equals("byte")) {
            System.out.println("Min Value="+Byte.MIN_VALUE+"\nMax Value="+Byte.MAX_VALUE);
        }
        else if(args[i].equals("short")) {
            System.out.println("Min Value="+Short.MIN_VALUE+"\nMax Value="+Short.MAX_VALUE);
            
        }
        else if(args[i].equals("int")) {
            System.out.println("Min Value="+Integer.MIN_VALUE+"\nMax Value="+Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        }
        else if(args[i].equals("long")) {
            System.out.println("Min Value="+Long.MIN_VALUE+"\nMax Value="+Long.MAX_VALUE);
        }
        else if(args[i].equals("float")) {
            System.out.println("Min Value="+Float.MIN_VALUE+"\nMax Value="+Float.MAX_VALUE);
        }
        else if(args[i].equals("double")) {
            System.out.println("Min Value="+Double.MIN_VALUE+"\nMax Value="+Double.MAX_VALUE);
        }
        else if(args[i].equals("char")) {
            System.out.println("Min Value="+(int)Character.MIN_VALUE+"\nMax Value="+(int)Character.MAX_VALUE);
        }
    }
```

Comment: как насчет заранее создать Map, заполнив её подготовленными значениями, и выводить уже из неё?

Comment: Нужно использовать более примитивный подход. Без Map. Нужно как-то используя логику сократить количество if до трех

Comment: Число `if` или число сравнений? Что преподаватель сказал дословно?

Comment: Дословно :The application should not contain more than three “if” and no switch/case statemen

Comment: Массив можно? ..

Comment: да. Есть идеи как это сделать массивом?

Comment: И со всем этим codegolf-ом пропустили (на мой взгляд) немаловажное условие: `Если ничего не передали вывести значения всех примитивных типов.` В двух ответах (из 4 имеющихся на текущий момент) это сделать довольно просто.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] types = {"byte", "short", "int", "long", "float", "double", "char"};
    int[] minValues = {Byte.MIN_VALUE, Short.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MIN_VALUE, Long.MIN_VALUE, Float.MIN_VALUE, Double.MIN_VALUE, (int) Character.MIN_VALUE};
    int[] maxValues = {Byte.MAX_VALUE, Short.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE, Long.MAX_VALUE, Float.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE, (int) Character.MAX_VALUE};
    
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < types.length; j++) {
            if (args[i].equals(types[j])) {
                System.out.println("Min Value=" + minValues[j] + "\nMax Value=" + maxValues[j]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Массивы минимумов и максимумов режут значения. Надо строки хранить.

Comment: Да,нужно будет кастировать,а соответственно лонги ,дабл ,флот не покажут достоверную ин-фу .Но в принципе  я попробую с этим поработать .Спасибо )

Comment: Сделала массив из Number и вроде все работает.Спасибо за вашу помощь)

Comment: Браво! Я проглядел отличное решение с единственным `if`. Браво!

Answer (score 5):

`Map` с сообщениями:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Temp {
    private static Map<String, String> messages = new HashMap<>();
    static {
        messages.put("byte"  , "Min Value=" + Byte          .MIN_VALUE + "\nMax Value=" + Byte          .MAX_VALUE);
        messages.put("short" , "Min Value=" + Short         .MIN_VALUE + "\nMax Value=" + Short         .MAX_VALUE);
        messages.put("int"   , "Min Value=" + Integer       .MIN_VALUE + "\nMax Value=" + Integer       .MAX_VALUE);
        messages.put("long"  , "Min Value=" + Long          .MIN_VALUE + "\nMax Value=" + Long          .MAX_VALUE);
        messages.put("float" , "Min Value=" + Float         .MIN_VALUE + "\nMax Value=" + Float         .MAX_VALUE);
        messages.put("double", "Min Value=" + Double        .MIN_VALUE + "\nMax Value=" + Double        .MAX_VALUE);
        messages.put("char"  , "Min Value=" + (int)Character.MIN_VALUE + "\nMax Value=" + (int)Character.MAX_VALUE);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        for(String arg : args) {
            System.out.println(messages.getOrDefault(arg, "Error"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Очень хороший подход, программистский )))Но нужно использовать более примитивный подход. Без Map. Нужно как-то используя логику сократить количество if до трех в этом и главная задача

Answer (score 3):

А если так попробовать:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        String className = args[i].replace("char", "Character").replace("int", "Integer");
        className = "java.lang." + className.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + className.substring(1);
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
        System.out.println("Min Value=" + clazz.getField("MIN_VALUE").get(null));
        System.out.println("Max Value=" + clazz.getField("MAX_VALUE").get(null));
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо ,но это немного мудренно для моего кол-ва знаний)

Comment: Применяя `replace` задачу можно решить без единого `if`. Просто `replace(arg, "нужное сообщение")` семь раз.

Comment: ну подставляйте 2 услоаных оператора вместореплейса, если реплейс не нравится.  по условию вроде как 3 можно. вопрос же не в реплейсе, а в другом подходе к решению.

Comment: Решение отличное!

Answer (score 2):

Ни одного `if`:

```
public class Temp {
    private static String[] types = new String[] {
        "byte"  ,
        "char"  ,
        "double",
        "float" ,
        "int"   ,
        "long"  ,
        "short"
    };
    private static String[] messages = new String[] {
        "Min Value=" + Byte          .MIN_VALUE + "\nMax Value=" + Byte          .MAX_VALUE,
        "Min Value=" + (int)Character.MIN_VALUE + "\nMax Value=" + (int)Character.MAX_VALUE,
        "Min Value=" + Double        .MIN_VALUE + "\nMax Value=" + Double        .MAX_VALUE,
        "Min Value=" + Float         .MIN_VALUE + "\nMax Value=" + Float         .MAX_VALUE,
        "Min Value=" + Integer       .MIN_VALUE + "\nMax Value=" + Integer       .MAX_VALUE,
        "Min Value=" + Long          .MIN_VALUE + "\nMax Value=" + Long          .MAX_VALUE,
        "Min Value=" + Short         .MIN_VALUE + "\nMax Value=" + Short         .MAX_VALUE
    };

    public static void main(String... args) {
        for (String arg : args) {
            int index = 3;
            index += 2 * Integer.signum(arg.compareTo(types[index]));
            index += 1 * Integer.signum(arg.compareTo(types[index]));
            index += types.length * Integer.signum(arg.compareTo(types[index]));

            String message = "Error";
            try {
                message = messages[index];
            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            }
            System.out.println(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Один `if`. Так немного честнее, так как при проверке `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` компилятор делает два `if`:

```
    public static void main(String... args) {
        for (String arg : args) {
            int index = 3;
            index += 2 * Integer.signum(arg.compareTo(types[index]));
            index += 1 * Integer.signum(arg.compareTo(types[index]));
            String message = "Error";
            if (arg.equals(types[index])) {
                message = messages[index];
            }
            System.out.println(message);
        }
    }
```

P.S. Не знаю как реализован `Integer.signum`. Если внутри два `if`, то получается всего пять.

Comment: Спасибо за вашу помощь. Очень интересно разобраться в этом коде. Но пока что это для меня за гранью) Мы даже Exception не проходили. А что делает метод сигнум ,даже прочитав документацию, не понимаю

Comment: Оооо, codegolf пошел :) А почему именно 10 на третьей итерации? Для красоты, или я чего-то не вижу, и есть реальная потребность использовать >7?

Comment: @kami, если третье сравнение не ноль, мы вылетаем за пределы массива.

Comment: это я понял. Если мы возьмем крайние случаи (после второго вычисления получили 0 или 6), то для выхода за пределы хватит и длины массива (7). Собственно, в этом-то и был вопрос, почему 10, которая вроде как не привязана ни к одной из составляющих задачи / решения. А вообще - код супер, так пожонглировать указателем на элемент массива .... :)

Comment: @kami, не я это придумал. Это вариант двоичного поиска. Добавил вариант без волшебной константы `10`.

Comment: @kami, спасибо! Убрал десятку, стало лучше.

Answer (score 2):

Один `if`. Так как `Map` запрещён, сделаем пародию на хеш-таблицу. Хешем будет код первого символа. Он случайно у всех типов разный:

```
public class Temp {
    private static class Type {
        public final String name;
        public final Number min;
        public final Number max;
        public Type(String name, Number min, Number max) {
            this.name = name;
            this.min = min;
            this.max = max;
        }
    };

    private static final Type[] index;
    static {
        index = new Type['s' + 1];
        index['b'] = new Type("byte"  , Byte          .MIN_VALUE, Byte          .MAX_VALUE);
        index['c'] = new Type("char"  , (int)Character.MIN_VALUE, (int)Character.MAX_VALUE);
        index['d'] = new Type("double", Double        .MIN_VALUE, Double        .MAX_VALUE);
        index['f'] = new Type("float" , Float         .MIN_VALUE, Float         .MAX_VALUE);
        index['i'] = new Type("int"   , Integer       .MIN_VALUE, Integer       .MAX_VALUE);
        index['l'] = new Type("long"  , Long          .MIN_VALUE, Long          .MAX_VALUE);
        index['s'] = new Type("short" , Short         .MIN_VALUE, Short         .MAX_VALUE);
    };

    public static void main(String... args) {
        for (String arg : args) {
            Type type = index[arg.charAt(0) % index.length];
            if (type != null && type.name.equals(arg)) {
                System.out.println("Min Value=" + type.min + "\nMax Value=" + type.max);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error");
            }
        }
    }
}
```